# Installing the SpringRoo Git addon issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-roo

I'm using version 1.2.3 of [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) on Linux Mint.

I want to install the Git addon and as per SpringRoo in Action, I'm doing this:

```
roo> addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.addon.git
Could not find specified bundle with symbolic name: org.springframework.roo.addon.git
```

As you can see it's failing to find it. I found a website which shows how to [search for addons](http://www.poornerd.com/2011/03/15/using-git-with-spring-roo-and-the-git-addon/) by doing:

```
roo> addon search git

0 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.2 compatible ID T R DESCRIPTION
```

This also failed, and didn't list anything. It appears a few other people
have [had this problem](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127572-addon-list-only-return-17-results-only-from-3-different-machine), but nobody seems to have found a solution.

Has anyone here successfully used the Git addon with SpringRoo?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use this:
roo> osgi start --url  file:///c:/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar
Then I can do:
roo> database reverse engineer --schema test

Not sure if this can apply to the git installation.

Answer (score 0):

The following code in roo shell worked to activate git add-on on Spring Roo 1.2.4

```
osgi obr url add --url http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/repository.xml
osgi obr start --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.addon.git
```

Based on information [here](http://lalyos.github.io/blog/2012/09/24/spring-roobot-workaround/) but I am using `osgi obr start` instead of `osgi obr deploy`